# Use self in singleton struct

Tags: swift, singleton

I have a simple question about singleton in swift, after a lot of research I didn't find a clear answer for that. So question is - I have a `StructA`:

```
struct StructA {
    static let shared = StructA()

    private init() {}

    public func someFuncA() {
       //self.somefuncB()
       //or
       //StructA.shared.someFuncB()
    }

    private func someFuncB() {

    }
}
```

I call `someFuncA` from other class like this `StructA.shared.someFuncA()`:

1. Can you please explain me what the difference  `self.somefuncB()` and `StructA.shared.someFuncB()` (see above code) ? 
   In my opinion there is no difference, but what if I have such code when `self.somefuncB()` must be called in callback -
2. So must I use `[weak self]`?

   ```
   public func someFuncA() {
       someFuncWithCallback() { [weak self] in
           self?.somefuncB()
       }
   }
   ```

   or can I just write

   ```
   public func someFuncA() {
       someFuncWithCallback() {
           StructA.shared.someFuncB()
       }
   }
   ```

   I checked this code with "Leaks" (Xcode instruments) it says that there is no leak, as I know closer/block owns objects that used in it, so can someone explain me what here happens ? thanks.

Comment: `self::method` forwards static calls while `Classname::method` doesn't

Comment: Since there can only be one instance of a singleton, `self.someFuncB` and `StructA.shared.someFuncB` are equivalent because self == StructA.shared; the use of `self` would be the simpler and more common approach. A singleton can never be released, so you don't have to worry about `weak`

Comment: @Paulw11 I got it ! You can post it as answer.

Comment: @Rob thanks for reply, so as I understand, I must write weak self to have more flexible code in future.

Comment: @Rob you wrote that - 
Singletons should be class, not struct. Value types are antithetical to singletons, I don't really understand what you mean, is this code wrong ? Why I must not use singletons with struct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. A `struct` singleton is a contradiction in terms. A singleton is an object where there should be only one instance. But `struct` is a value-type and has "copy" memory semantics. Consider:

   ```
   var a = StructA.shared
   ...
   ```

   The `a` is a copy of the so-called singleton, not a reference to it. To avoid this problem, the singleton should be a `class`, a reference type.
2. I agree with Paulw11, that `self` is a simpler and more common approach.  I'd also suggest, though, that by referencing `self`, you can better write code that (a) is not dependent on the class being a singleton; and (b) opens the possibility of the class being subclassed at some future date.
3. Given that I would advise `self` pattern, I would therefore also suggest avoiding obvious potential strong reference cycles (e.g. by employing `weak` or `unowned` references where needed). There's no point in knowingly creating what could be strong reference cycle simply because it happens to be a singleton. Why write code that you know you'd have to rewrite if you ever revisited the decision to use singleton pattern, especially when you know how easy it is to avoid strong references in the first place?
4. FYI, I'm seeing the same behavior that you report, that if a `static` participates in a theoretical strong reference cycle, it's not identified as such. But if you set that `static` property to `nil` (assuming it was variable and optional), the strong reference appears.

   This observation doesn't change my recommendation above, namely to avoid what you know would be a strong reference cycle in any other context. I'm merely confirming your empirical observation.

Regarding points 2 through 4 above (where I contemplate some potential eventual refactoring of singleton pattern into some other pattern), I should say that this is not a purely academic observation. It's not uncommon to have some singleton type, and later, as the project becomes more complicated or employs more unit tests, to revisit that decision and start employing dependency injection or other patterns. It would be a shame if you had to edit all of the individual functions as well. If you write the code to not depend upon the singleton nature of the object, you end up with more robust code base with fewer unnecessary internal dependencies.